# importing of java file from one module to another module in maven project is throwing classNotFoundException

Tags: spring, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to create a Spring maven project in multiple module. Just assume, there is Maven project with below module:

Module-root(parent Module of all submodule)
Module-persistance(Having code logic for DAO operation and package type jar)
Module-service(Having code logic for controller implementation and package type war)

Now importing spring.xml file from one module to another module is working fine but but here I am getting error while deploying the war, HibernateCfg.java is a file defined in module Module-persistence and imported this file in the Module-service.

Compilation and Build of all module is successful but at the time of deploying the Module-service war file on the 
server, and It is throwing `ClassNotFoundException` for "HibernateCfg".

I checked the war file, inside of that Module-persistance.jar file is available with class file of HibernateCfg but I am not sure why it is throwing exception.

Could anyone help me with this below exception:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.munsiji.hibernateUtil.HibernateCfg from [Module "deployment.munsiji-service.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: first run the maven clean, refresh you project by right click on the project and refresh thereafter run as > maven install, wait to build till success, if there is everything ok in your pom.xml and project resources, then the error will gone...

Comment: No... it is not helping. i am not sure why jar file of Module-persistance module is not adding to the Module-service war file. Since, if i will add manually  Module-persistancet.jar to the war file it is working fine. any idea with that ????

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue recently so thought to update here as well. The reason behind issue was, maven artifact type of maven Module-service is web and for Module-persistance is also web maven artifact type. So when i was trying to do full publish in the Wildfly server from the Eclipse itself, the folder structure was wrong due to web.xml in Module-persistance as Eclipse considered Module-persistance as web module and created the folder structure accordingly.

But if I will copy the Module-persistance jar file manually inside the Module-service war file and run the wildfly server, there was no error as folder structure for jar is fine as needed. but this is a work around solution.

Actual solution of the problem: what i did, i changed the maven artifact type of Module-persistance to "maven quickstart" from the "maven web" artifact type. And now it is working fine even i can deploy it from the Eclipse itself. Hope it make sense. :)